# Delete user with command

Tags: proftpd

I would like to know that how to **delete a user** in proftpd created with command:

```
adduser username-GroupManager --in group ftpusers --home /home/username/somewhere/
```

I have not found anything on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vi /servers/proftpd/etc/passwd 
shift + /meteo - search file for user meteo 
dd - delete line
esc + !wq + enter
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

How to delete а ProFTPd virtual user run this command

```
ftpasswd --passwd --delete-user --name=qs3_1553011872_7558 --file=/etc/proftpd/ftpd.passwd
```

How to delete а ProFTPd virtual group run this command:

```
ftpasswd --group --delete-group --name=qs3_1553011872_7558 --file=/etc/proftpd/ftpd.group
```

source: https://orbisius.com/blog/how-delete-proftpd-virtual-users-and-groups-p4637